# Replace publish date in blog module with custom field

Tags: customization, custom-field

I use Wordpress + the Divi visual builder

What I want to do is replace the published date for a custom field (publish date for a custom date in the future)

So I can date and add custom text in the place of the publish date meta

How would I do this?

see attached image

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGoer.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Divi, but if you are using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for the custom fields you'd use [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) in your template.